# How to hide specific site referral links using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, hide, referrals

I would like to hide specific site name traffic (referral) from google analytics and similar web etc. for example I wat to that specific site traffic to be shown not as a referral but direct traffic with htaccess? I searched similar questions "how to hide affiliate link with htaccess but that not helping me.

Comment: What would this this have to do with .htaccess? This is something that should be done within your analytics tools, there should be ways to filter out any data ou don’t want to see.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I didn't mean that. I want all traffic from a specific domain (ex: blablasite.com) to be detected as direct traffic, not as a referral. Can I do that with .htaccess?

Comment: You would have to modify / unset the incoming request’s referrer header then, using https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader

Comment: Huh, looks complicated, can get some start code to work with if it is not to much trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can conditionally unset the `Referer` HTTP request header in `.htaccess` - when the request is coming from the domain you want to appear as "direct" - this only changes what the *server* sees.

The *browser* has already computed the *referrer* before making the HTTP request (it does, after all, form part of the request). And this is what's assigned to the JavaScript `document.referrer` property (that Google Analytics uses) in the browser. The *server* plays no part so cannot influence this.

However, the `document.referrer` JavaScript property is read-only. Attempting to assign anything to this property has no effect. So, trying to reset this property *before* the GA code is not going to change what GA reports.

You'll need to somehow change how GA is reporting this in GA itself, or bypass GA altogether?

> similar questions "how to hide affiliate link with htaccess...

Note that *affiliate* links aren't usually based on the HTTP Referer (which is unreliable), but on a parameter (affiliate ID) in the URL itself.

Comment: Updated answer to make it specific to the one domain.

Comment: Hi thanks, but not working I have replaced "example" with site name without .com and analytics still detect as a referral...hmm

Comment: @TempleDerr the analytics code probably reads this via JS on the client side. I am not sure, if unsetting this request header on the server side, actually influences what the browser will provide in `document.referrer`. You might need to overwrite the latter, before you embed your analytics codes.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work on this to find a solution

Comment: @CBroe Ah yes, of course, the browser populates `document.referrer` (or at least knows what it is) _before_ the request is sent to the server. Unsetting on the server is obviously too late. However, it seems `document.referrer` is read-only, trying to change this in the browser has no effect. So, I can't really see how/if this could be done, without doing something directly with Google Analytics? (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: So, is there any other way to achieve this? Javascript or...?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Well, there is potentially one way... and that's to override/customise the Google Analytics script itself that you include on every page (including the minimised `analytics.js` file downloaded from Google - there are 6 direct references to a `referrer` property on the `document` object). You could potentially clone the `document` object, set the `referrer` property to whatever you like and use your custom object in the script instead. Needless to say, this would not be recommended!